# How to open port 25 on the server

Tags: linux, centos, smtp, email

I'm using centOS.

I want to implement a smtp mail server, and I have installed postfix and dovecot(both have been set correctly).

I tried to telnet the 25 port, but it returns  `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

So, How can I open the 25 port? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

make sure postfix is listening on the external IP for port 25. By default it only looks on 127.0.0.1:25

If you have this

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
```

Put a # in front of that line and remove the comment from

```
#inet_interfaces = all
```

Then restart postfix

```
service postfix restart
```

Comment: I have done this setting already.

Comment: This answer is pretty old, but solved my problem. Thank you @mike

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually have a service listening on that port you would do something like the following to open up the firewall if the ip of your server is `172.16.1.20`:

```
sudo iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 5 -p tcp -d 172.16.1.20 -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

You want to list the rules with:

```
sudo iptables -L -n --line-numbers
```

To make sure you put it in the right place. [Here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) is a tutorial that covers the basics of iptables with CentOS.

Comment: Note that sudo is not set up for any users in the default configuration on CentOS

Comment: It returns iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Comment: It would also be handy if you could run:
netstat -nltp

that will show what proceses are listening on what ports on TCP.

Comment: EN      1869/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LIST

Comment: Oh ya, after the change if all is good you want `service iptables save`

Comment: service iptables save  still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution

Edit

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Add the following line in

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

Restart iptables

```
service iptables restart
```

Comment: Unloading iptables modules: Applying iptables firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 7 failed

Comment: I edited the line to put in your iptables script

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this on CentOS is probably to use this utility:

```
sudo /usr/bin/system-config-securitylevel-tui
```